# mutiple schema validation payloadvalidatingInterceptor with samenamespace

Tags: spring-ws

I'm using the schemas property on the PayloadValidationInterceptor but it only validates payload request correctly for the first XSD schema location defined in the list.

```
<property name="interceptors"> <list> <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint .interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor"> <property name="schemas"> <list> <value> /WEB-INF/xsd/PaymentSubmission.xsd </value> <value> /WEB-INF/xsd/Notifications.xsd </value> </list> </property> <property name="validateRequest" value="true" /> <property name="validateResponse" value="true" /> </bean> </list> </property>
```

Note:Xsds are sharing same namespace.plz give the solution

Comment: <property name="interceptors">
<list>
<bean
class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint .interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
<property name="schemas">
<list>
<value>
/WEB-INF/xsd/PaymentSubmission.xsd
</value>
<value>
/WEB-INF/xsd/Notifications.xsd
</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
<property name="validateResponse" value="true" />
</bean>
</list>
</property>

Answer (score -1):

Create one uber.xsd and inlude others into.